# CORS error when trying to post message

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, yammer

I have an AngularJS Application I am trying to post a message through. I am successfully able to log the user in, get the access token, and I have ensured I have my domain in the JavaScript Origins within Yammer.

Whenever I try to post a message, however, I get the following error:

[image: Image of console error]

The strange thing is when it does the preflight it seems OK but as the error states I can't figure out why it isn't coming back in the CORS header as I have it registered within the Yammer Client area.

Here is the code for posting:

```
    $scope.YammerPost = function (Yammer) {
        var _token = Yammer.access_token.token;
        var config = {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + _token
            }
        };
        $http.post('https://api.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json', { body: 'blah blah', group_id: XXXXXXX }, config);
    }
```

I call that scope variable in the view via a button click.

Here is the logic I use to sign the user in:

```
    function checkYammerLogin() {
        $scope.Yammer = {};
        yam.getLoginStatus(
          function (response) {
              if (response.authResponse) {
                  $scope.Yammer = response;
                  console.dir(response); //print user information to the console
              }
              else {
                  yam.platform.login(function (response) {
                      if (response.authResponse) {
                          $scope.Yammer = response;
                          console.dir(response);
                      }
                  });
              }
          }
        );
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us the code? Also, what browser is this? I know IE behaves differently.

Comment: Use fiddler to see the actual headers.  If on Linux, use wireshark.

Comment: I added the code I use to log the user in and also the code I am using for posting the comment.

Comment: Did you add localhost in the javascript origins of yammer? Not entirely sure if that will work, can you double check with another (not localhost) domain?

Comment: So far as I can tell, it looks like the adal.js library I am using for AD authentication is passing an Authorization token that is not being overwritten by my logic above for some odd reason... not sure why Angular wont let me override it.

Comment: How do you manage to add "localhost" origin on yammer? Shouldn't yoo uadd your IP or domain on yammer and then access your app via that IP or domain and not via localhost? If your ip changes offten you can use free service from http://www.noip.com

Comment: It's based on what they have listed in their documentation here: https://developer.yammer.com/docs/app-registration

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding the issue.

For some odd reason, every time I would try to use an $http post it would include an Auth token from AD (app using Azure AD for authentication).

I ended up using jQuery inside of my Angular scope function on the button click and it works as I can control the headers for the request.

```
$.ajax({
                url: 'https://api.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json',
                type: 'post',
                data: {
                    body: 'this is a test from jQuery using AngularJS',
                    group_id: <group_id>
                },
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': _token
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    console.info(data);
                }
            });
```

Fixed the issue and I can now post.

If anyone sees any issues with this practice please let me know, still a little new to angular